# DataTable row limit

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Morning,

Regarding the following quote, is this limit independent of how many columns there are? (Im assuming not but its not specifically stated anywhere.) If it is linked to the number of columns, how do you calculate that your not over this limit?

> To add rows to a DataTable, you must first use the NewRow method to return a new DataRow object. The NewRow method returns a row with the schema of the DataTable, as it is defined by the table's DataColumnCollection. The maximum number of rows that a DataTable can store is 16,777,216. For more information, see Adding Data to a DataTable.

["Link to where quote was taken from."](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm also assuming not. Each DataRow is a separate object, so the structure of the DataTable is reasonably independent of the contents of those.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would expect that limit (which is 2<sup>24</sup>) to be independent of the number of columns. I expect that it's just a single 32-bit integer internally is used to represent the row count as 24-bits and 8 bits are used for flags or something similar.

In practice, 16 million rows is going to take a *long* time to populate and a *lot* of memory... if you're in danger of hitting that limit, you should probably be rethinking how you're accessing data to start with.

Comment: Thanks for replying. i was planning to use a Datatable to upload data from a text file into sql sever via bulk copy. I was concerned that the amount of data i was going to upload would exceed this limit so i was planning to split the datatables up among a couple tasks + check that each tasks datatable didnt exceed this limit.

Is the above a poor approach?

Comment: @HansRudel: I would split the data up into a smaller number of rows than that anyway, to be honest. I haven't used SQL Server bulk copy myself, but I'd expect that it would be easier to show regular feedback etc if you split it into sections of (say) 100,000 rows.

Comment: @HansRudel - You should not even need to use C# to do this -- SQL Server provides direct CSV import facilities.

Comment: @Mr Skeet:Thanks very much for your help/suggestions, its much appreciated.

Comment: @Hogan: Its a little challenge i had set myself. I wasnt aware that it had that facility though so thanks for bringing it to my attention.

Comment: @HansRudel - NP, the typical way this problem domain is solved is using SSIS.  There is a small learning curve but it is basically easy -- SSIS will be easier to build, maintain and run faster (even for a one-off).

Comment: With that amount of data, you want to implement your own IDataReader and pass it to the SqlBulkCopy. Don't use an intermediate DataTable, it's going to be quite wasteful.

Comment: @zmbq- Am i correct in assuming that the IDataReader would be reading/inserting 1 row at a time??

Answer (score 0):

It is not linked to the number of columns, except in so far as your memory has an upper limit so if you have so many columns you can't store the rows in memory you could get an out of memory error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DataTable.Rows.count to check the current row count before adding the new row

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question.